# Solving hid.lib "unresolved external symbol" linker errors in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors, .lib

As the title suggests, I am having the following linker error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "unsigned char __stdcall
>   HidD_GetAttributes(void *,struct _HIDD_ATTRIBUTES *)"
>   (?HidD_GetAttributes@@YGEPAXPAU_HIDD_ATTRIBUTES@@@Z)

when calling `result = HidD_GetAttributes(WriteHandle, &attributes)` in my code.

This function should exist in "hid.lib" which I have added to my linker dependencies for the project.  I have also included the header file "hidsdi.h" which has the function prototype for HidD_GetAttributes.

The only other thing that I thought might be problematic is that the function prototypes for "hid.lib" are split between three different headers: hidsdi.h, hidpi.h, and hidsage.h.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just solved the problem. Apparently "hid.lib" was written in C which was resulting in some name mangling. Using

```
extern "C"
{
    #include "hidsdi.h"
}
```

cleared everything up.

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I just spent almost an hour having the same problem … why don't they say so on MSDN!?

Comment: from my experience, microsoft's documentation is not that great.  most of the problems i had were fixed by messing around with my code or searching forums.  glad this was helpful to you.